# Jaxb Unmarshalling java files from XML file with namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Example" xmlns="http://www.Example.com/1" xmlns:football="https://www.Example-football.com/xsd/football-ext">
    <metadata>
        <name>hello world</name>
        <time>2018-04-26T12:32:52</time>
        <extensions>
            <sportsMeta>
                <football:length>5080.3714454417996</football:length>
            </sportsMeta>
        </extensions>
    </metadata>
</gpx>
```

Added this to package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.Example.com/1", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED, xmlns = {
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "football", namespaceURI = "https://www.Example-football.com/xsd/football-ext"),
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "https://www.Example-football.com/xsd/football-ext/1/1") })
package com.example.football.share.gpx;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

I am able to read name, time. But not able to read guid, length.

Here is SportsMeta.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sportsMeta", propOrder = {
        "length"
})
public class SportsMeta {

    protected BigDecimal length;

    public BigDecimal getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(BigDecimal length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
}
```

How can I read length info from the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML input you have this part:

```
<sportsMeta>
    <football:length>5080.3714454417996</football:length>
</sportsMeta>
```

where the namespace prefix `football` refers to the namespace URI
`"https://www.Example-football.com/xsd/football-ext"`
as defined by `xmlns:football="https://www.Example-football.com/xsd/football-ext"`
in your XML.

To map this XML to Java correctly you need to specify
that namespace URI for the `length` property of your`SportsMeta` class.
You do this by annotating the `length` property
with `@XmlElement` *and* specifying the namespace within there.
(See also the [API documentation of `XmlElement.namespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#namespace--).)

```
@XmlElement(namespace = "https://www.Example-football.com/xsd/football-ext")
protected BigDecimal length;
```

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Fritsch, it worked.
You are a savior, I spent whole day to fix this by trying different approaches.
Thanks lot.